# DOM Selectors in jQuery for elements that do not have ID or CLASS name tags

Tags: jquery, dom, google-chrome, css-selectors, chromium

How do I use jQuery to select DOM elements that do not have ID or CLASS name tags?

I noticed that Chrome debugger shows the DOM location on the bottom taskbar which is very helpful.

QUESTION:
What would be the jQuery() selector for the following DOM element?

Here is a screenshot of my Chrome Debugger.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing a complex query selector use something like this:

```
$("table").eq(1);
```

This selector will grab the second table on the page